# HTML/JQuery Sorting subtables and making certain rows unsortable?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Layout: A table with rows that have an "expand" button. The expand button shows all children of that row, all of which share some common data with the parent row.

Goal: drag children between parents; i.e. move a certain subset of data to another set, and automagically edit certain fields based on the new parent's data.

So far, I have the table with expanding subrows, but I can't wrap my head around how to make the children draggable between parents. I do not want to be able to reorder the parent rows either, they should be static. The table is dynamically created, with data being fetched from a database.

The table:

```html
    <table id="loot-table" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Min Level Required</th>
                        <th>Min Tokens Required</th>
                        <th>Type of Loot Dropped</th>
                        <th>Loot Group</th>
                        <th>Name of Loot Dropped</th>
                        <th>Quantity of Loot Dropped</th>
                        <th>Weight of Loot Dropped</th>
                        <th>Loot Is Available:</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php $loot_group_count=-1; foreach($event['lockbox_loot'] as $lockbox_loot){ $loot_group_count++; ?>
                        <tr class="loot-header-row">
                            <td><input type="number" value="<?php echo $lockbox_loot['min_level_required']; ?>"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" value="<?php echo $lockbox_loot['min_tokens_required']; ?>"></td>
                            <td><input name="loot_group_id[<?php echo $loot_group_count; ?>]" type="text" value="<?php echo $lockbox_loot['loot_group_id']; ?>"></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><a href="#" class="loot-table-expand-btn" data-group-id="<?php echo $loot_group_count; ?>">Expand</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php if($loot){ $i=-1; foreach($loot as $lootitem){
                            if($lockbox_loot['loot_group_id'] === $lootitem['loot_group_id']){ $i++; ?>
                            <tr class="loot-row-<?php echo $loot_group_count; ?> hide">
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><input name="item_loot_group_id[<?php echo $loot_group_count; ?>][<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="text" value="<?php echo $lootitem['loot_group_id']; ?>" disabled="disabled"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="loot-type[<?php echo $i; ?>]">
                                        <option value="money" <?php if($lootitem['loot_type']==="money"){echo "selected";}; ?>>Money</option>
                                        <option value="respect" <?php if($lootitem['loot_type']==="respect"){echo "selected";}; ?>>Respect</option>
                                        <option value="item" <?php if($lootitem['loot_type']==="item"){echo "selected";}; ?>>Item</option>
                                        <option value="mafia" <?php if($lootitem['loot_type']==="mafia"){echo "selected";}; ?>>Mafia</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><input name="loot_id[<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="text" value="<?php echo $lootitem['loot_id']; ?>"></td>
                                <td><input name="quantity[<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="number" min="0" value="<?php echo $lootitem['quantity']; ?>"></td>
                                <td><input name="loot_weight[<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="number" min="0" value="<?php echo $lootitem['loot_weight']; ?>"></td>
                                <td><input name="is_available[<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $lootitem['is_available']; ?>" <?php if($lootitem['is_available']){echo "checked";}; ?>></td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php }}}} ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

The JQuery Code for expanding the hidden cells:

```jquery
    $(".loot-table-expand-btn").each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            var group_id = $(this).attr('data-group-id');
            $('.loot-row-' + group_id).each(function(){
               if($(this).is(":visible")) {
                   hidden = true;
                   $(this).hide();
               } else {
                   hidden = false;
                   $(this).show();
               }
            });
            if(hidden) {
                $(this).html('Expand');
            } else {
                $(this).html('Collapse');
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI - Sortable has a [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) on how to share draggable children between parents. As for limiting the sorting to certain rows, or `<td>`'s you can use that same API and select only the elements you want/need with the "items" option, for example

`items: "td[class='mark']"`

Would let you sort items with that class only.